# Can someone explain This behaviour inside of method?

Tags: javascript, object

Hi Beginner here so sorry for any ignorance if I showed.

```
const test = {
    myfunction(){
        console.log(this);
    },
    myfunction3(){
        function myfunction4(){
            console.log(this)
        }
        return myfunction4()
    } }
```

and when I run

```
test.myfunction3()
```

I receive global object as a window. I am a little bit confused how this happened. My question is

1. `myfunction3()` can access to `myfunction4()` because of its hierarchy? If so, is there anyway I can access to `myfunction4()` directly instead of going through myfunction3()?
2. Why `this` in `myfunction4()` returned global window instead of a reference to `myfunction4()`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: "*is there anyway I can access to `myfunction4()` directly instead of going through `myfunction3()`?*" - no. `myfunction4` is a local variable inside `myfunction3`, it is only created once you call `myfunction3()`

Comment: Why would you expect `this` to be a reference to `myfunction4`?! Have a look at [how the `this` keyword works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/1048572)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. You cannot access myfunction4 in such method of "test.myfunction3.myfunction4()"**

Because myfunction4 is not property of myfunction3 and especially, test.myfunction3 is not object.

**2. Since myfunction4 is not method, instead it is function, "this" refer Window object in myfunction4.**

"this" in method refer the parent object but in function, it refer global object like Window.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the global object has to do with your function call/invocation and not with the function placement itself.

Invocation, I'm referring to ==> test.myFunction3()

Object methods often times are a bit confusing, but just because a function sits inside of another function means nothing. It's not about placement of a function but its invocation.. so here what matters is test.myFunction3()

Comment: "so here what matters is test.myFunction3()*" - no, for the `this` value in `myFunction4`, the call to `myFunction3` does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

> myfunction3() can access to myfunction4() because of its hierarchy? If so, is there anyway I can access to myfunction4() directly instead of going through myfunction3()?

You can't access the function directly through `myFunction3()`, but you can return a reference to it, which you can then use. See below where I point out that you have a typo in your implementation of `myFunction3()`

```
const func4 = myFunction3();

func4();
```

> Why this in myfunction4() returned global window instead of a reference to myfunction4()?

There are two issues, first `this` in a function is bound at runtime.

Second, because of typo in `myFunction3()` you are returning the result of calling `myFunction4` rather than returning a reference to the function itself, which I assume is what you are trying to do.

```
myfunction3(){

    function myfunction4(){
        console.log(this)
    }
    return myfunction4; // this returns the function, rather than return the result of calling the function (drop the () )
}
```

Comment: "*which I assume is what you are trying to do*" - I'm pretty sure OP isn't. I doubt they know about closures if they don't even know about scopes.

Comment: Perhaps. Perhaps. Perhaps. Or, it's possible, they aren't thinking about closures, and instead just thinking about returning the function?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just needed to convert it into an object for the function call to work like this:

```
var name = 'global';   // when 'this' scope is global

var test = {
    name: 'local',   // when 'this' scope is local to test
    fun1: function() { //same fun as an object
        console.log(this.name);
    },
    fun3: function() {
        function myfunction4(){
            console.log(this.name);
        }
        return myfunction4()
    } 
}
```

And if you wanted to call the functions in the same way you were doing it above, then you could it have done so like this:

```
test.fun1();     // local

test.fun3();    // global (that's what inside of fun4)
```

You cannot call fun4 directly but can findout the value by calling fun3.